Change Data Capture (CDC) on JDBC to Pub/Sub ingested from Cloud SQL on PostgreSQL
Are there any way to implement "Change Data Capture (CDC) on JDBC to Pub/Sub ingested from Cloud SQL on PostgreSQL" that no replay messages occur?

Hi @Muhannad Bashar, Could you check these documentations link1, link2, where you can use pgoutput plugin for your requirement ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

As mentioned in this documentation, you can get postgres logical replication changes using pgoutput plugin , all the steps related to the logical replication is provided in the above documentation.
Also, as per your requirement, you can consider using Change Data Capture (CDC) with PostgreSQL, Debezium, Kinesis, and EventBridge, for detailed information and steps you can follow this documentation.
